# USB Debugging hang (Android Studio Android 6)

Tags: android-studio, usb-debugging

I´m new with programming with Android Studios.

I try to debug my application. It starts but it hang with in the process "Installing APK". The processbar in the statusline on the bottom of the screen from AndroidStudios (version 2.2.3) did not go further and I have to kill this process to try it again.

I think I set the settings of my mobilephone (Honor 7, Android 6, API Level 23) for USB-Debugging right, because I can install and start the app from the laptop.

It is interesting that I have to start the installation of the app, secondly on my mobilephone. That is new, with my last mobilephone (Acer V370, Android 4.2, Level 17) that was not necessary. Additionally I tried the same procedure on the mobilephones (Acer) from my family. They have Android 6 and no EMUI (4.0.1) and it worked great without any problems.

Could it be that my EMUI (4.0.1) (standard on smartphone from Huawai) causes this problem? (Maybe this is helpful - German website about EMUI: https://www.huaweiblog.de/emui-wiki/)

Can somebody help me or has somebodyelse an idea to solve the problem?

I would be very glad if somebody could help me.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: What section do you need? My app includes many classes and four Activities (That is my first question on Stackoverflow).

Comment: As a check, click on the make project (hammer icon) and make sure that the the project is associated with the correct build. The Run/Debug configuration should normally be set to app.